# Unable to connect web exception mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

we are doing a facebook posting application using HttpWebRequest.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    //doing some stuff here.
}
```

This code is failing at line uisng with unable to connect to server exception.
This is not failing always, but it is failing in 90% cases.

Can somebody advise how best this can be addressed?

Comment: When does it fail?  You said it fails only 90% of the time...

Comment: if I run, it will fail, if I run again it will connect. and again next time it will fail. majority is failure. If run 5 times, it will connect once and will fail 4 times like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (this may not be an answer; just trying to debug your issue), see if it fails like your other one does; then try replacing google.com with your own URL:

```
WebRequest g = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
var response = g.GetResponse();
```